# How can I delete all the columns in the Dynamic DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, model-view-controller

First, I want to delete all the columns and then use the select command to bring all the columns back for perform the refresh operation on the DataTable without refreshing page. So I need a piece of code that I can delete all the columns.
I shared my html and javascript code as shown following.
Can someone help me about this regard?

```
//CSHTML
<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-bigboy" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th class="disabled-sorting">Room Plan</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
              <tr>
                  <th>Room Plan</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th class="text-right">Actions</th>
              </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody id="colmn">
              @*  *@

          </tbody>
 </table>


//*********************************JS*********************************//
//-------------------------SELECT ROOM START----------------------------

$.post("/Home/selectRooms", {}, function (data) {

    var ndx = 0;
    $.each(data.xroom_name, function (key, value) {

        var Xroom_name = data.xroom_name[ndx];
        var Xroom_plan = data.xroom_plan[ndx];

        var column =
          ('<tr>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<div class="img-container">' +
            '<img src="../../assets/img/room-plan/' + Xroom_plan + '" alt="..." id="imgsrc">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td id="imgname">' + Xroom_name + '</td>' +
            '<td class="text-right">' +
            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>' +
            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>' +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>');

        document.getElementById('colmn').innerHTML = document.getElementById('colmn').innerHTML + column;

        ndx++;

    });
});
```

I also delete the column information that I clicked like this:

```
var table = $('#datatables').DataTable();
  table.on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        table.row($tr).remove().draw();
        e.preventDefault();
  });
```

I want to delete all columns because of I can refresh the table immediately after adding, updating and deleting. I do not want to delete the column that I clicked only.

Comment: "I do not want to delete the column I clicked only." So you mean want to delete all columns?

Comment: yes! Of course.

Comment: I guess you could just do `$('#colmn').html('')` which basically deletes all inside it? Or did i misunderstand?

Comment: This does not work because of the structures that I use. But thanks anyway

Comment: Why not exactly (to understand better what you looking for)?

Comment: From the code that I see you are actually removing tr( table row) on click ,you can simply empty the table body (which is the initial state in your case ) using $("#colmn").html("");  or $("#datatables> tbody").html(""); Also please update the question to delete all rows ,instead of columns.